# Typescript ignores explicitly stated ANY type and treats variable as type object if _.isObject() is used on the variable, causing property name errors

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

When I have a variable typed "any" and do a lodash check for _.isObject, and then try to access properties on the variable, it raises the typescript error `error TS2339: Property 'propertyName' does not exist on type 'object'.`

My expectation is that typescript continues to treat the variable as `:any` because that's what is explicitly declared, and that it allows accessing any properties on the object without raising typescript errors.

---

## Example

### No object check, no typescript error:

```
const myObjectVariable: any = service.getObject();
this.anotherVariable = myObjectVariable.propertyName;
```

### Object check causes error:

```
const myObjectVariable: any = service.getObject();
if (_.isObject(myObjectVariable) {
    this.anotherVariable = myObjectVariable.propertyName;
}
```

Raises: `error TS2339: Property 'propertyName' does not exist on type 'object'.`

**Why is this happening where typescript ignores the original type and treats it as an object, and can I turn it off or make it stop without changing the code?**

Comment: That is pretty interesting, and actually make sense. Typescript is probably inferring that the type because `_.isObject` returns true. That is pretty cool. I guess an easy fix would be to cast to any `this.anotherVariable = (myObjectVariable as any).propertyName;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this *might* be a bit of an oversight in how narrowing from `any` was implemented.  Lodash's `isObject()` method is a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) that narrows its argument if it returns `true`, but this interacts with `any` in a way that you are not happy with.

---

Originally, when one invoked a type guard that narrows to some specific object type on a value of type `any`, it would not narrow at all and stay `any`.  This bothered people, because the compiler should be able to catch errors like this:

```
interface Foo { x: string; }
declare function isFoo(x: any): x is Foo;
declare const v: any;

if (isFoo(v)) {
    v // still any
    v.x.toUperCase(); // no error?
}
```

This was raised in [microsoft/TypeScript#9999](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9999) and fixed in [microsoft/TypeScript#10334](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10334).  So now one gets the following desirable behavior:

```
if (isFoo(v)) {
    v // Foo
    v.x.toUperCase(); // error!
    // Property 'toUperCase' does not exist on type 'string'. Did you mean 'toUpperCase'?
}
```

---

But the intent was not to narrow from `any` no matter what.  The intended logic is represented in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9999#issuecomment-239058747): narrowing from `any` to primitives or specific object types is desirable, but narrowing to `Object` or `Function` is not, because those types are nearly useless and `any` is preferable.

So if lodash's `isObject()` were typed like the following:

```
interface LoDashStatic {
    isObject(value?: any): value is Object; // Object 
}
```

then you wouldn't have the problem:

```
if (_.isObject(myObjectVariable)) {
    // still any
    this.anotherVariable = myObjectVariable.propertyName; // okay
}
```

But `isObject()` is actually declared like this:

```
interface LoDashStatic {
    isObject(value?: any): value is object; // lowercase o object 
}
```

That's using `object`, not `Object`.  The `object` type means "non-primitive object" and was introduced in [TypeScript 2.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) via [microsoft/TypeScript#12501](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12501).  That was *after* the narrow-from-`any` PR was done.

In other words: at the time the logic for when to narrow from `any` was hashed out, there was *no* `object` type to consider.  Possibly they would have included `object` along with `Object` and `Function` as an exception.  Or maybe not; it's hard to say for certain.  Maybe someone could even file a new [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) in GitHub asking to prevent narrowing from `any` to `object` using the issues linked here as justification.

But for now, that's just the way it is, and `any` is narrowed to `object`:

```
if (_.isObject(myObjectVariable)) {
    // object
    this.anotherVariable = myObjectVariable.propertyName; // error!
}
```

---

So what can you do as a workaround?  Well, you could always use your own custom typing for `isObject()` that uses `Object` instead, via [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#introduction):

```
// merge into lodash typings
declare module 'lodash' {
    interface LoDashStatic {
        isObject(value?: any): value is Object; 
    }
}
```

Or you could use type assertions to "widen" back to `any`:

```
this.anotherVariable = (myObjectVariable as any).propertyName; // error!
```

Or, since [`any` is a problematic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any) in general, you might want to give `myObjectVariable` a more accurate type, representing what you actually know about it.  For example, maybe you know it could either be a `string`, a `number`, or some object with a `propertyName` property of type `string`.  Then you'd use this instead:

```
const myObjectVariable: string | number | { propertyName: string } = service.getObject();
if (_.isObject(myObjectVariable)) {
    // {propertyName: string}
    this.anotherVariable = myObjectVariable.propertyName; // okay
}
```

and be happy that the compiler removed `string` and `number` and left you with the object type.  (That's just an example; you could use `{ [k: string]: any } | undefined` instead... or some other union of types in which the `object`-compatible one can be indexed at the `propertyName` key.)

If you can't do this in your code then you can't, but it's what I'd recommend most strongly because it uses TypeScript's compiler to help keep your code type safe, instead of looking for ways to keep your code *unsafe* by persisting `any`.

---

Anyway, hope that explains the situation and gives you some options to proceed.  Good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1&ts=3.9.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7IB4BcyAzmFKAOYDcyAvgFAAmECANnFCjAK4gJjB0IZMGIZ0ACkLI4IAJ4BKInhHE0mKkxbtOyBENLIAbkVlzN9YDGQTR4iUYUKc9ZG+PIA9J-XpX7owA6PECwdABVAAdoAGE4YggJBRpvZGgodCgAQn83VIAFDOioMDlkAHIwqNj4iHLkRnQINRB0MDS8UXahZFLoitJyEApywOQAEWBGZDl0bmQAWwhZCqrI4riE8oB+egZ6b096SwXIzPaAKhk1AH1kGAyFitZ0RniAC3KLZjYOFAXXtxWChyi83sRPi53CJwNB4EhkAAZdDjD4AZTAcAECCh0PcogA8gAjABWLDADjgrG4EG2pnkSmMVJpqmQ6FJ5JSPheAHdoAhamy2Rz+MhcnQ9lpfrp9CBDAkoEZgEgiLgKBAwMSyfwkvSyrQLL9iGoAEIcXFuWRtd7QABqHGAcCJwL1mmhSzA71eSQteNlhgWci15Pt5CdLpk8mQAF4SNAlUhAurNSKKclxdCrDYboFCamJIHg-xQ47nRAnL68e5UuztWAM1Xeu9RIErZ67Q7wyhY4XUyWu4FIkVoKUAHJwJZctJQDLZBtVz0tts2qD9ssxmy9utr4HXSOKQfDkpyceTrw+dKZHLziXQhjujVexgAJh92Bv-vaW5DnbLREGlDIAAPsgIDcAsRLQMBODIEO6DFGOE4QP+ZCAbQG4KgmEBJhqRZpm6jZZhIOZ5nWBZBn2v7AhW76NniqTYHBCEnkhKFDBQ950e4i7EK2rTtquVHdosFHbkJh7wSOLFnjWADWcByDenFuMpiyPq8ADMb4fgYX6iT+YZ-jBADaslsZQAC6ep0NBvDMDAoAQNMsaYcq2HJnhSQEVWREkcQnnfsWQk0Te0IMaZ5nDFZ+6qXRPF8daHaGbuPb6UFyXYUxUmnhAU7oPJil0ap+ySvQRqmnAABevrLklpYRmYFi0EAA)

Comment: or use bracket notation e.g. obj['propertyName'] to avoid a typescript error

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to use the native javascript `typeof` like this `typeof data === 'object'`.

Be carefull though if your data is `null` this will still return `true` as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#typeof_null)